# “Silence” and “silently”: What is the name of the relation between these words?

Tags: terminology, morphology, derivational-morphology

Consider:

- *Silence* is a noun.
- *Silent* is an adjective.
- *Silently* is an adverb.
- *Silence!* is an interjection.

Not sure how these words actually evolved, but they were likely all derived from the noun *silence*. What is the name of this noun-derived relationship?

Comment: You silence people with interjections?

Comment: @tchrist I'm not known for it, but if the need arose I would :) http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/interjections.htm http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/08/22/people-saying-silence-in-movies_n_933025.html

Comment: I think the last item is mis-labelled. An interjection is generally a kind of emotional outburst like 'ouch' or 'yikes'. You might mean 'Silence!' as a command (say, by a teacher). In which case, that's a noun.

Comment: @Peter It looks like a noun, but it's being used as an exclamation / interjection here. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection).

Comment: It also exists as a verb, as in 'he silenced the court with his evidence'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: but an interjection is not a part-of-speech. It will still have a part-of-speech label. If someone issues a command, 'Fire!' you could say that is an interjection. However, 'fire' continues to be a verb. It is only words like 'ah!' or 'oh!' that are purely exclamations.

Comment: @Peter Do I say 'Oh yes it is!' here? [EnglishClub](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/parts-of-speech_1.htm) certainly designates interjections as a part of speech. Words can exhibit categorial polysemy. You're challenging a dictionary's judgement here ([RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/silence)), which lists the interjection usage along with the noun and verb usages – **silence** interj. 
8. be silent!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: We shall probably not see eye to eye on this. I cannot find this label in any other dictionary I see. I see 'Silence!' as being equivalent to 'Silence, please!' or even 'Pray silence'. Similarly 'Quiet!' is a kind of truncated version of 'Can I have quiet please?'

Comment: So you wouldn't class 'Humbug!" (doubtless = 'This is humbug / nonsense!') as an interjection? AHD, RHK Webster's, Wiktionary, Dictionary.com, YourDictionary do (but not Collins) of the first 7 dictionaries I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

They are simply *derived* versions of the noun.  This is quite common:

"The *strength* of steel is without equal."

"The bond between them is *strong."*

"I *strongly* urge you to consider this answer."

Answer (score 0):

It's called ***nominalisation*** (more popularly, ***nounification***). From [Wikipedia...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization)

> ***nominalization*** or **nominalisation** is the use of a verb, an adjective, or an adverb as the head of a noun phrase, with or without morphological transformation.

OP's isn't a very good example - most of us have no idea which of ***silent, silence*** came first in English, so we can't easily identify the *original* and the [***derivative***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(linguistics)) forms.

A better example might be the recent usage *"That's a big **ask**"*. Although in reality the word ***ask*** has been used as a noun for centuries, most of us will interpret the usage of the last few decades as an example of [anthimeria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthimeria) (non-standard use of a word, in this case using a verb as a noun).

Comment: So why not verbification? (I'll leave the other parallelifications.)

Comment: @Edwin: Why not indeed? It just so happens OP didn't include any ***verbs*** in his examples so I didn't bother to explicitly mention the term. But it's covered in my link to ***anthimeria***.

Comment: Nounification is conversion **to** a noun.

Comment: @Edwin: I know that. What I *don't* know, as implied by my answer, is whether there was some original verb ***to silence*** or adjective ***silent*** which led to the derivative noun form ***silence***. But I don't particularly *want* to know that - the interrelationship almost certainly predates "English", so it's a bad example for talking about how we *currently* derive new words (or "part-of-speech" usages) from existing ones. Although my ***ask*** usage involves "conversion/zero-derivation", I still think it's a more useful example.

Answer (score 0):

“How these words evolved” is a question about etymology.

The noun “silence” comes from Old French, which inherited it from Latin silentium. It is used in English since the Middle English period (the oldest references in the OED are from the early 13th century).

The adjective “silent” is a Renaissance borrowing directly from the Latin adjective silens (accusative form: silentem). It is attested in English since 1565. Silentem and silentium have a common root in Latin, but from an English standpoint they are two different words, borrowed at two different periods.

The verb “to silence” is a de-nominal derivation from the noun “ silence”. It is attested from 1616 onwards.